# Where to store the images on Server-side and not to store in the static folder and How to retrieve them on request?

Tags: node.js, server-side

I am creating a Nodejs website and the website is about selling photos, although I will store the images on the static folder but in the low quality or watermarked. But When the user Purchases that image, I want to give him the link of the image through a secure connection. Please Guide me sensei! I am new to the developer's world and doing a real project for the first time. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know what a GUID is? I would store the thumbnail and high rez images all in the same folder, with a GUID as the filename of each (so that its not guessable) and just send the buyer the link to the high rez photo whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, I recommend looking at online services. You can store the preview images in a Amazon S3 bucket, and give access to them via CDN. The benefit to this is that your server does not have to bear the load of all of the image requests, converting the base64 for transfer, you don't have to keep your server running, etc. When someone orders, you can process the full-size into drop-box delivery utilizing Amazon's Lamda service, and send notification with a link for delivery.

Or you can store the images in the database. Just remember you would have to read them out of the database with your back-end, perhaps encode them into Base-64, then render them with a custom front-end.

Since this is a software engineering forum, I must ask, what made you choose NodeJS? Did you draw out the solution first? The reason I ask, is that NodeJS is not a good fit for high capacity, and images can be high capacity depending on your audience.

Knowing as little as I do about your problem, I would still suggest something serverless for your backend, and depending upon how complex your application will end up being, Angular or Vue.